# On button click get text of many divs with the same class and paste it inside input fields with the same class using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three input fields with the same css class `price-input` and i want after clicking on the button with id `set-price-btn` to fill them with the default price displayed at the bottom of each input field using pure JavaScript.

Here is my code but doesn't work. What I am doing wrong?

```js
var setpricebtn = document.getElementById("set-price-btn");

var items = document.getElementsByClassName("name");
var priceinputs = document.getElementsByClassName("price-input");



setpricebtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  var savedprice = items[i].innerText;
  priceinputs.value = savedprice;
}





  });
```

```css
.toolbar {
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
margin-bottom:30px;
}

.btn {
width:auto;
display:inline-block;
padding:10px;
text-align:center;
background:#e8e8e8;
cursor:pointer;
border-radius:4px;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="toolbar">
<div class="btn btn-primary" id="set-price-btn"> Set price to all fields </div>
</div>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-3 item">
<input name="price" placeholder="Enter price" class="price-input" value="" min="0" type="number">
<span class="name"> 150 </span>
</div>

<div class="col-3 item">
<input name="price" placeholder="Enter price" class="price-input" value="" min="0" type="number">
<span class="name"> 175 </span>
</div>

<div class="col-3 item">
<input name="price" placeholder="Enter price" class="price-input" value="" min="0" type="number">
<span class="name"> 547 </span>
</div>




</div>
```

Comment: It is better (safer) if you will control the relations of the elements `.name` to `.price-input`.
Ie, get click event on `.price-input` then get the `.name` as related element (u can use `nextElementSibling`).
Or get the nearest parent element of the clicked input, then change the values of its own children elements (`.name` and `.price-input`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your javascript, change `priceinputs.value` to `priceinputs[i].value` will resolve the issue.

Comment: I checked my code many times and i wasn't able to detect this !! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem. You need to add [i] in your priceinputs.value in order to differentiate each element.

```js
var setpricebtn = document.getElementById("set-price-btn");

var items = document.getElementsByClassName("name");
var priceinputs = document.getElementsByClassName("price-input");

setpricebtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  var savedprice = items[i].innerText;
  priceinputs[i].value = savedprice;
}
});
```

```css
.toolbar {
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
margin-bottom:30px;
}

.btn {
width:auto;
display:inline-block;
padding:10px;
text-align:center;
background:#e8e8e8;
cursor:pointer;
border-radius:4px;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="toolbar">
<div class="btn btn-primary" id="set-price-btn"> Set price to all fields </div>
</div>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-3 item">
<input name="price" placeholder="Enter price" class="price-input" value="" min="0" type="number">
<span class="name"> 150 </span>
</div>

<div class="col-3 item">
<input name="price" placeholder="Enter price" class="price-input" value="" min="0" type="number">
<span class="name"> 175 </span>
</div>

<div class="col-3 item">
<input name="price" placeholder="Enter price" class="price-input" value="" min="0" type="number">
<span class="name"> 547 </span>
</div>




</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`priceInputs` is also an array-like object like `items` so you need to access each input by index just like `items[i]`. Change `priceInputs.value` to `priceInputs[i].value`. Below example uses `.querySelector()` and `.querySelectorAll()` but other than that nothing but the bracket notation `[i]` is different. Also removed `#id` because it'll just be a hindrance in the future.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector(".btn");

var items = document.querySelectorAll(".name");
var prices = document.querySelectorAll(".price-input");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    prices[i].value = items[i].innerText
  }
});
```

```css
.toolbar {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.btn {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #e8e8e8;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="toolbar">
  <div class="btn btn-primary"> Set price to all fields </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3 item">
    <input name="price" placeholder="Enter price" class="price-input" value="" min="0" type="number">
    <span class="name"> 150 </span>
  </div>

  <div class="col-3 item">
    <input name="price" placeholder="Enter price" class="price-input" value="" min="0" type="number">
    <span class="name"> 175 </span>
  </div>

  <div class="col-3 item">
    <input name="price" placeholder="Enter price" class="price-input" value="" min="0" type="number">
    <span class="name"> 547 </span>
  </div>
</div>
```