# On button click get values of many input fields with the same class and paste it inside different input fields with the same class using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Based on a previous question of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68056208/on-button-click-get-text-of-many-divs-with-the-same-class-and-paste-it-inside-in) i have three input fields with the same css class `price-input` and i want after clicking on the button with the id `set-price-btn` to fill them with the input value displayed at the bottom of each input field using pure JavaScript.

The problem is that everytime i click the button, the variable `videosize` returns undefined. What I am doing wrong ?

```js
var setpricebtn = document.getElementById("set-price-btn");

setpricebtn.addEventListener("click", () => {

var priceinputs = document.querySelectorAll("price-input");
var videosize = document.querySelectorAll("video-file-size").value;

for (var i = 0; i < videosize.value; i++) {
  var savedprice = videosize[i].value;
  priceinputs[i].value = savedprice;
}

  });
```

```css
.toolbar {
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
margin-bottom:30px;
}

.btn {
width:auto;
display:inline-block;
padding:10px;
text-align:center;
background:#e8e8e8;
cursor:pointer;
border-radius:4px;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="toolbar">
<div class="btn btn-primary" id="set-price-btn"> Set price to all fields </div>
</div>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-3 item">
<input name="price" placeholder="Enter price" class="price-input" value="" min="0" type="number">
<input name="uf" class="video-file-size" value="155" type="text">
</div>

<div class="col-3 item">
<input name="price" placeholder="Enter price" class="price-input" value="" min="0" type="number">
<input name="uf" class="video-file-size" value="185" type="text">
</div>

<div class="col-3 item">
<input name="price" placeholder="Enter price" class="price-input" value="" min="0" type="number">
<input name="uf" class="video-file-size" value="314" type="text">

</div>




</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things to remember:

This is how you query based on classes when using `querySelector`. You have to use a `.`.

videosize will be a **[live collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)** of HTML Nodes.

```
var priceinputs = document.querySelectorAll(".price-input"); 
var videosize = document.querySelectorAll(".video-file-size");

for (var i = 0; i < videosize.length; i++) {
  var savedprice = videosize[i].value;
  priceinputs[i].value = savedprice;
}

  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do `var videosize = document.querySelectorAll("video-file-size").value` because `document.querySelectorAll("video-file-size")` returns a NodeList. See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

And either you use `document.querySelectorAll(".video-file-size")` or `document.getElementsByClassName('video-file-size')`.